# Filter out sublist in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, rule-engine

I am a newbie user in mathematica. Here is my problem:

For example, I have a nested list:

```
 lst = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {1}, {0,3}}
```

I want to only output those sublist whose elements are 0 or 1. The above list's output should be:

```
{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1}}
```

I can get the list that satisfies my conditions with this:

```
lst /. x:{(1 | 0) ..} :> x
```

But how can I get the converse of the pattern? like this:

```
 lst /. x:NOT{(1 | 0) ..} :> Sequence[]
```

So that i can get the result in one stroke.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice application for some/every:

```
some[f_, l_List] :=                          (* whether f applied to some     *)
  Scan[If[f[#], Return[True]]&, l] === True  (*  element of list is True.     *)

every[f_, l_List] :=                         (* similarly, And @@ f/@l        *)
  Scan[If[!f[#], Return[False]]&, l]===Null  (*  (but with lazy evaluation).  *)
```

So first make a function that checks a sublist for all zeroes/ones:

```
chk[lst_] := every[#==0||#==1&, lst]
```

Then filter your list-of-lists for sublists that pass the test:

```
Select[lst, chk]
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
Select[lst, every[#==0||#==1&, #]&]
```

Comment: thanks, dude! From your clue, i have another solution: Case[lst, {(1 | 0) ..}]

Answer (score 6):

Starting with:

```
lst = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {1}, {0, 3}};
```

You can filter with this:

```
Cases[lst, {(1 | 0) ..}]
```

Or get the complement with either:

```
Cases[lst, Except @ {(1 | 0) ..} ]
```

or:

```
DeleteCases[lst, {(1 | 0) ..}]
```